# Creating html nodes from DOM in java

Tags: java, tree, jsoup, html-parsing, traversal

I tried using JSoup to convert Html document to Html nodes in java. While crawling through the Document how to check if child nodes are present in current node? Any other method of crawling through the document but with nodes will be highly appreciated.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://www.websitetocrawl.com").get();
List<Node> listOfRequiredNodes;
for(Node node : doc.childNodes()){
       documentTraversal(node);
   }
}

public void documentTraversal(Node node){
    if(node==null){
        return;
    }
    if(node.hasAttr("table")){
        listOfRequiredNodes.add(node);
    }
    // here if node do not have child, i get error
    for (Node n : node.childNodes()) {
        documentTraversal(n);

    }
}
```

Comment: Why not select the correct element directly with a selector? Without the actual url it is hard to help you.